# tweenmax animations Cannot assign to read only property '_gsTweenID'

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap, scrollmagic

I'm using scrollmagic to animate objects while scrolling and I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '_gsTweenID'
>   of #design-principles

my JS code:

```
var scale_tween = TweenMax.to('#design-principles', 1, {
    transform: 'scale(.75)',
    ease: Linear.easeNone
});

controller = new ScrollMagic();

var scale_scene = new ScrollScene({
    triggerElement: '#style-and-performance'
}).setTween(scale_tween);

controller.addScene([
    scale_scene
]);
```

Comment: Your code looks okay. Please provide a fiddle or pen showcasing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I received this same error when I ran a transition on an object, then attempted to run a second transition on the same object.

If you hit this error, console log the object on which you are running your transition. If you see a property `_gsTweenID` on that object, delete it. This allowed greensock to write to the object, which facilitated the transition.

Answer (score -2):

The reason is that tweenmax fails to find the `'#design-principles'` element.
Maybe it's not available yet? (wait for document ready)
Make sure the selector is correct by trying to use only TweenMax, before adding ScrollMagic functionality.

Comment: code is wrapped in function and called on window load event

Comment: That's not really enough proof tbh... Try `console.log($('#design-principles').length);` right where you initiate the tween.
And Again I would ask you to create a pen or fiddle so we can have a better look at this instead of guessing.